# How to copy a circular queue to a larger array in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, queue

I'm trying to copy a circular queue to a larger array in Java. Obviously if the array is not circular (i.e, [1, 2, 3, 4] where 1 is the front and 4 is the back) I can use the arraycopy method.

However how would I copy the elements to a larger array preserving the order. For example, if the array was [1, 2, 3, 4] but 4 is the front and 3 is the back, when copied to a larger array with twice the capacity, it should result in [4, 1, 2, 3, _, _, _, _].

```
public void add(int s) {
        if (size >= capacity) {
            int[] bigger = new int[capacity * 2];
            if (front <= back) {
                System.arraycopy(queue, front, bigger, 0, capacity); #error here
            } else {
                System.arraycopy(queue, front, bigger, 0, capacity-front);
                System.arraycopy(queue, 0, bigger, capacity-front, front);
            }
            front = 0;
            back = queue.length;
            queue = bigger;
            capacity *= 2;
        }
        
        queue[back] = s;
        back = (back + 1) % capacity;
        size++;
    }
```

This is my current code, and it works well on some runs but on other runs I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds on the first arraycopy method and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Could you try setting an exception breakpoint for any thrown `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` in your IDE, or alternatively setting a breakpoint within the JDK code where the exception is thrown? The issue might be that you check for `<=`. So when the queue is full, but `front` is at an index > 0, the copy will be out of bounds. It should probably check `<`, or better `front == 0`; because `front < back` will never be true for a full queue due to your `back = (back + 1) % capacity` assignment at the end.

Comment: @Marcono1234, you're right. Thanks so much!